# Is it possible to open a PDF file from Objective-C at a heading?

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

Is it possible to programmatically open PDF files in MacOS with Preview from Objective-C at a particular heading?
[Is it possible to open PDFs with Preview.app at a certain page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941104/is-it-possible-to-open-pdfs-with-preview-app-at-a-certain-page) provides a way of opening a specified page using Applescript but I would like to go to a specified heading as shown in the left-hand panel of Preview.